# Facebook Open Graph properties not working: "The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, facebook-sharer

So I have this website: http://asimpleforexguide.com/

I have already specified the Open Graph properties with an app_id generated from Facebook.

```html
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="277549136353523" />
<meta property="og:title" content="ASDFG - A Simply Direct Forex Guide" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.asimpleforexguide.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.asimpleforexguide.com/img/bg-mobile-icon.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Learn Forex Trading from setting up accounts, to setting up trades." />
```

But whenever I share the link, or try it in Facebook Sharing Debugger, I get these errors.

> Inferred Property
>   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>   Missing Properties
>
> The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id